# When/why should I return from a BackboneJS model/collection extend function?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to BackboneJS and taking a look at this article on [Smashing Magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/backbone-js-tips-patterns/) and I am wondering when/why should an extension function return a model/collection/something.

```
var Hotel = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: {
        "availableRooms": ["a"],
        "rooms": [
            {
                "name": "a",
                "size": 1200,
                "bed": "queen"
            },
            {
                "name": "b",
                "size": 900,
                "bed": "twin"
            },
            {
                "name": "c",
                "size": 1100,
                "bed": "twin"
            }
        ],

        // how come this function does not return
        getRooms: function() {
            var rooms = $.extend(true, {}, this.get("rooms")),
             newRooms = {};

            // transform rooms from an array back into an object
            _.each(rooms, function(room) {
                newRooms[room.name] = {
                    "size": room.size,
                    "bed": room.bed
                }
            });
        },

        // but this one does
        getRoomsByBed: function(bed) {
            return _.where(this.getRooms(), { "bed": bed });
        }
    }
});
```

Please be kind. I am not trying to rip apart someone else's code - I am just trying to understand how Backbone works. :-)

Thanks

Comment: Backbone uses "classes" which JS doesn't really have. In this case, you're doing specification. Hotel is a specification of a model. ( inb4, yes- yes I know Backbone is bad for not using plain JS objects for models)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think about the `extend` -function used in Backbone as a reference towards the OO-world, where classes are usually extended to create SubClasses. In Javascript, these 'classes' have to be stored in variables (e.g. declaring classes in Java) to make them available for the application to use.

So you could see this:

```
var Dog = Mammal.extend({...});
var dog = new Dog();
```

as a version of this

```
class Dog extends Mammal { ... }
Dog dog = new Dog();
```

So the Backbone extension function returns a 'subclass' of the 'class' being extended. Of course, Javascript is nowhere near object -oriented, so don't take this literally, but the concept is somewhere around the same ballpark.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. So this prototypal inheritance, right? But how come `getRooms` returns and `getRoomsByBed` doesn't? I also have problems with `collection.fetch()` which in my mind should be `var c = collection.fetch()` I hope you see where my confusion is :-)

Comment: I think that `getRooms` not returning is a bug, as it is used by `getRoomsByBed` in a way that implies it returning an array/object.